# Tcl/Tk tablelist row selection by mouse over event

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to bind the event "Enter" with a Tcl/Tk [tablelist](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html) so that whenever I hover my mouse over the table the row selection follows it. This feature is needed for my application as there is a right click menu associated with the selected row.

Currently I can select one row and move mouse and right click in other row to popup the context menu, which is misleading i some times.[image]

This problem may be handled in another way by enabling selection by "button-3" press event binding. But I want to avoid that. But can not really achieve the mouse-hover selection. Please guide.

Comment: Focus-follows-mouse style GUIs are really out of fashion, and with good reason: they suck, usability-wise. Are you sure that this is the right thing to do? (Making B3 do some kind of selection is the usual approach for dealing with this, even though it's often a temporary selection which reverts after the button is released. Getting bindings right is non-trivial.) You don't say why you don't want to use B3…

Comment: Actually,I don't really have a strong reason for Not using B3. Maybe that's a mistake i am making. I will follow ur suggesion of using it. 

lately I have realized that as my tablelist is updating at a 100 ms interval, mouse-over binding may be a real bad choice.